# mongodb update (insert array inside array) PHP

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

```
{
    "_id" : "9127194b5bcebc099877d6192647412572892576",
    "id_store" : "a907b33f4a3141ad2086815d841554b3f7dbe15a",
    "created_on" : ISODate("2016-03-01T06:18:39.000Z"),
    "product" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "1967e1f0158a8589d49d9ffb8fe5236cf4d4482f",
            "kategori" : "pakaian",
            "created_on" : ISODate("2016-03-01T06:21:08.000Z"),
            "jenis_barang_umum" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : "2dc12dec915f1ad013d8bc8610ed8d6cafea6995",
                    "jenis_barang_umum" : "baju",
                    "created_on" : ISODate("2016-03-01T07:52:26.000Z")
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : "8d0fd34d9c96c82fd736772fd02eb01cf13d4561",
                    "jenis_barang_umum" : "celana",
                    "created_on" : ISODate("2016-03-01T07:52:32.000Z"),
                    "jenis_barang_spesifik" : [ 
                        {
                            "_id" : "1b14e9be168dc762713e35c453a91ceb653638ebb",
                            "jenis_barang_spesifik" : "jeans",
                            "created_on" : ISODate("2016-03-01T07:52:40.000Z")
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : "1b14e9be168dc762713e35c453a91ceb65e638e8",
                    "jenis_barang_umum" : "jaket",
                    "created_on" : ISODate("2016-03-01T07:52:40.000Z"),
                    "jenis_barang_spesifik" : [ 
                        {
                            "_id" : "1b14e9be168dc762713e35c453a91ceb65e638ebb",
                            "jenis_barang_spesifik" : "jaket kulit",
                            "created_on" : ISODate("2016-03-01T07:52:40.000Z")
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "d839e4dd9ba895f7733a6713a653ae9fcf7b79b9",
            "kategori" : "aksesoris",
            "created_on" : ISODate("2016-03-01T06:21:13.000Z"),
            "jenis_barang_umum" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : "4855847d579f31c17925218a5723764a8f0fc10a",
                    "jenis_barang_umum" : "topi",
                    "created_on" : ISODate("2016-03-01T07:42:36.000Z")
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : "6a7a917f6e139552e3883594b73a67fb6fa4ad27",
                    "jenis_barang_umum" : "gelang",
                    "created_on" : ISODate("2016-03-01T07:47:22.000Z")
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : "8bd3428f2ac106c5323af1defe125675f08afcf3",
                    "jenis_barang_umum" : "kalung",
                    "created_on" : ISODate("2016-03-01T07:47:28.000Z")
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have document like that, how syntax for inserting new array inside jenis_barang_spesifik (my data inside jenis_barang_spesifik added by robomongo so I dont know how the syntax is).

Here is my syntax for inserting new array into jenis_barang_spesifik but it didn't work. Hope you guys can help me :D

Thanks

```
$ar_jenis_barang_spesifik = array(
                  '_id' => hash('sha1', time() . $jenis_barang_spesifik),
                  'jenis_barang_spesifik' => $jenis_barang_spesifik,
                  'created_on' => new MongoDate()
              );
$result = $jenis_barang_spesifik_collection->update(array('product.jenis_barang_umum._id.' => $jenis_barang_umum), array('$push' => array('product.$.jenis_barang_umum.$.jenis_barang_spesifik' =>$ar_jenis_barang_spesifik)));
```

Comment: Can you please try to include the actual code in your question instead of images because code in images can't be copied and pasted into an editor and compiled in order to reproduce the problem. Among many other reasons why it's not generally recommended to post images of code here on SO, images are large and hard to read on mobile devices, they can't be searched and therefore aren't useful to future readers.

Comment: ah, sorry for that, im already change the image.